# Unique elements of a list and corresponding indices in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Given a list `vs`, I want to get the list `vs'` of the unique elements of `vs`, as well as the indices of the elements of `vs` in `vs'`. For example, if `vs = [7, 8, 7, 8, 9]` I want to get `[7,8,9]` (the unique elements) and `[0,1,0,1,2]` (the indices).

An easy implementation is:

```
import           Data.List
import           Data.Maybe

unique :: Eq a => [a] -> ([a], [Int])
unique vs = (vsnub, indices)
  where
  vsnub = nub vs
  indices = map (\v -> fromJust $ elemIndex v vsnub) vs
```

However I think this is not efficient. I've done an implementation using mutable vectors. The pseudo-code is (saying that `vs` is a list of numbers):

```
n = length of vs
idx = list of n integers (to store the indices)
visited = [false, false, ..., false] (n elements)
nvs = list of n numbers (to store the unique elements)
count = 0 
for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
  if(not visited[i])
  {
    nvs[count] = vs[i]
    idx[i] = count
    visited[i] = true
    for(j = i+1; j < n; ++j)
    {
      if(vs[j] = vs[i])
      {
        visited[j] = true
        idx[j] = count
      }
    }
    count ++
  }
}
nvs = first 'count' elements of nvs
```

And here is my Haskell code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import           Control.Monad               ((>>=))
import           Data.Vector.Unboxed         (Unbox, Vector, freeze, (!))
import           Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable (IOVector, new, write)
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable as VM

unique' :: forall a . (Unbox a, Eq a) => [a] -> IO (Vector a, Vector Int)
unique' vs = do
  let n = length vs
  idx <- VM.replicate n 0 :: IO (IOVector Int)
  visited <- VM.replicate n False :: IO (IOVector Bool)
  nvs <- new n :: IO (IOVector a)
  let inner :: Int -> Int -> Int -> IO ()
      inner i j count | j == n = return ()
                      | otherwise =
                        if vs !! i == vs !! j
                          then do
                            write visited j True
                            write idx j count
                            inner i (j+1) count
                          else inner i (j+1) count
  let go :: Int -> Int -> IO (IOVector a)
      go i count | i == n = return $ VM.take count nvs
                 | otherwise = do
                   vst <- VM.read visited i
                   if not vst
                     then do
                       write nvs count (vs !! i)
                       write idx i count
                       write visited i True
                       _ <- inner i (i+1) count
                       go (i+1) (count + 1)
                     else go (i+1) count
  nvs' <- go 0 0 >>= freeze
  idx' <- freeze idx
  return (nvs', idx')
```

Is it nice? Can it be improved? Is there a solution that does not resort to `IO`?

Comment: Hmm.. I've done some benchmarks and the second implementation is highly slower than the first one.

Answer (score 2):

#### Various Comments

First, Stack Exchange sent the body of my response into the void when I logged in to post it, so I'm going to be a bit more brief and a bit less organized than I originally wanted because I'm lazy.

This is not really reviewing your code, so it would've been better served as a comment, but I didn't think to comment my approach before I wrote out all the code. Might as well share it in case it's helpful.

To be honest, I don't quite understand your second solution, but on a second read it looks like it might still be `n^2` (same asymptotic complexity as your first solution), so that would explain why it's slower. I assumed at first it was just something to do with mutability and vectors (which I don't really understand myself), but on second read I'm no longer so sure about this.

If you don't mind me being frank in answering your first question: I don't really think it's nice. I had a pretty rough time reading it, to the point where I instead just wrote a more Haskell-inclined solution that has better asymptotic performance than your first one.

#### Proposed Solution

Are you okay with an `n log n` solution? If memory serves, with the right choice of set/map, the `log`'s base is so large that it is effectively linear.

Here is one such solution

```
import Data.List (foldl', sortOn)
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as Map

-- | Gives the unique elements of 'elems' in order.
orderedNub :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
orderedNub elems = sortOn (firstIndexMap Map.!) (Map.keys firstIndexMap)
  where
    -- Insert such that if the value is already in 'firstIndexMap', it is not
    -- updated.
    addElem m (elem, index) = Map.insertWith (flip const) elem index m
    -- Left fold in order to get the first occurance of each element.
    firstIndexMap = foldl' addElem Map.empty $ zip elems [0..]

-- | Gives the unique elements of 'elems' and the indices of 'elems' in
-- the unique list of elements.
unique :: Ord a => [a] -> ([a], [Int])
unique elems = (uniques, indices)
  where
    uniques = orderedNub elems
    uniqueInds = zip uniques [0..]
    indexMap = foldr (uncurry Map.insert) Map.empty uniqueInds
    -- We can use unsafe indexing since we know that 'indexMap' has
    -- the right values.
    indices = [indexMap Map.! x | x <- elems]
```

#### Some Notes About the Solution

1. I changed the code so it is correct now, assuming you want to preserve order. Some of these comments may be a bit out of date as a result.
2. `orderedNub'` is a kind of clunky definition, but it should have better asymptotic performance than `nub`. I’m pretty sure you can avoid the overhead of an actual sort (one clunky way would be to use a vector like you’re using).
3. `uncurry Map.insert` is a cute pointfree thing, if that's not your dig just sub it with a lambda or helper function.
4. I can't think of a good way to avoid using `Map.!`, even though it's partial. If I used `Map.lookup`, then there'd have to be a `fromJust` or a `Maybe` overhead, even though the map is, by construction, going to have the right keys. Guess this is a shortcoming of the type system.

Comment: You can also use [`Set.findIndex`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.0.1/docs/Data-Set.html#v:findIndex) rather than creating a `Map`

Comment: @4castle Do we know the input will be sorted?

Comment: No, but `Set.fromList` sorts its input.

Comment: @4castle Unless I’m mistaken, this would then give for the input [9, 8, 7, 8, 7] the output [7, 8, 9], [2, 1, 0, 1, 0]. I’m not sure if this is what the OP wants.

Comment: Your code already gives that output. `nub'` is producing a sorted list.

Comment: @4castle Ah crap, let me fix that then. Thanks for pointing that out.